# Material UI | How to change the font colour of a disabled input text field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The colour of a disabled input text field created using material UI is light grey by default and it is not very visible against a white background. Is there any way to change the **font colour** of a disabled input text field?

Answer (score 23):

Below is an example of how to do this showing the customized version next to the default styling.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const DarkerDisabledTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    marginRight: 8,
    "& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled": {
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)" // (default alpha is 0.38)
    }
  }
})(TextField);

export default function Demo() {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setDisabled(!disabled)}>Toggle Disabled</Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <DarkerDisabledTextField
        disabled={disabled}
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Custom"
        value={`Disabled = ${disabled}`}
        variant="outlined"
      />
      <TextField
        disabled={disabled}
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Default"
        value={`Disabled = ${disabled}`}
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Disabled text color]

Comment: For me changing the font color only worked with - WebkitTextFillColor: red -

Comment: @F.Fabian for chrome worked `WebkitTextFillColor: "red"` but for safari we have to use `color:"red"`

Answer (score 16):

In the Mui-v5 above solution is not working.
Below are the solutions for Mui-v5.
Solution 1:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  input: {
    "& input.Mui-disabled": {
      color: "green"
    }
  }
});
```

Solution: 2 (use `sx` property for the component)

```
sx={{
    "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {
      WebkitTextFillColor: "#000000",
    },
  }}
```

eg.

```
<TextField
      fullWidth
      disabled=true
      variant="outlined"
      sx={{
          "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {
            WebkitTextFillColor: "#000000",
        },
      }}
  />
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest way is to create an object to define the font color and pass it to the TextField's inputProps.

```
    const fontColor = {
        style: { color: 'rgb(50, 50, 50)' }
    }
```

This way you can toggle the font with the components state as you wish or simply keep it constant.

```
<TextField
    label="Title"
    onChange={updateTitle}
    value={title}
    disabled={true}
    inputProps={fontColor}/>
```

Answer (score 5):

works (MUIv5):

```
sx={{
    "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {
      WebkitTextFillColor: "#000000",
    },
  }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { TextField, styled } from '@mui/material'

const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)({
  '& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled': {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
});
```

Then use them as standard component

```
<CustomTextField
            name="manual"
            label="Manual"
            size="small"
            disabled={watch({}).platform === 'manual' ? false : true}
          />
```

if u use RHF with controller, mean u create custom TextField using RHF, u just change the component inside the styled()

For example:

```
import RHFTextField from "../RHFTextField"

const CustomTextField = styled(RHFTextField)({
  '& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled': {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
});
```

with background color changes, it will more visible..

Answer (score 1):

None of all the many answers online worked for me, using MUI v4.

Finally I found a very easy but hacky solution for setting the font color of a disabled TextField component.

The problem is, (at least for Firefox) it will use this weird style cheet:

```
.css-[...]-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input.Mui-disabled {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}
```

I'm too new to this stuff and I don't know how to change it, so my way was to overwrite it:

```
.css-[...]-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root input {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6) !important;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

The `!important` part is important!

In React with MUI v4, it's as simple as that:

```js
    const textFieldColor = /*...*/;
    const textFieldSX = {
        input: {
            "-webkit-text-fill-color": `${textFieldColor} !important`,
            color: `${textFieldColor} !important`,
        },
    };
    /*...*/
    <TextField sx={textFieldSX} />
```

Just in case, this `-webkit-text-fill-color` property would turn into `color` one time, one can use an `!important` there too.